# Scala - generate Array of bytes based on range

Tags: arrays, scala, byte

I am trying to solve a (possibly) trivial problem. I would like a nice, concise way to instantiate Array of bytes based on range. So far this works

```
Array(1 : Byte, 2 : Byte)
```

but I would like to use sth like

```
((1: Byte) to (10: Byte)).toArray
```

this is however `Array[Int]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range` is not generic; it inherits from `IndexedSeq[Int]`, so there's no way to make a "`Range` of `Byte`". (Edit: See Daniel C. Sobral's answer for a generic range type!)

When you try `((1: Byte) to (10: Byte))`, the `Byte`s are implicitly converted back to `Int` again.

How about:

```
(1 to 10).map(_.toByte).toArray
```

That will result in two passes over the collection; if that's an issue, a non-strict view will rectify that:

```
(1 to 10).view.map(_.toByte).toArray
```

Answer (score 3):

While [Ben James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189179/ben-james) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16320127/53013) is true enough, *there is* a more generic range for any type `T` for which there is an `Intergral[T]`: `NumericRange`.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange
NumericRange(1: Byte, 10:Byte, 1: Byte).toArray
```

Another alternative would be mapping the resulting array to byte instead of mapping the range. For example, and using an `Array` method:

```
Array.range(1, 10).map(_.toByte)
```

Comment: +1, I noticed `NumericRange` as I was writing that answer, but didn't investigate enough!